# Edge passwords and saving to a homeshare for citrix

Tags: passwords, group-policy, citrix

I want to save Edge passwords to a new computer.

I have read a ton of articles and everyone says `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\`  or specifically the login data there.

So I can save that whole folder and try and import it in and the passwords are not there. I am basically doing this for Citrix and I can sync the roaming Microsoft folder and the local credentials folder and it saves correctly to the profile server, thus it works when I log off and get a new VDI.

My problem is when I have to wipe out a profile (which I have to from time to time) that data is goes bye bye from the profile server. So for the bookmarks I do a log off script which copies some of that  \default\ folder (bookmarks, cookies, favicons and login data) to the users z drive and I import it in nicely with a login script. But I can't seem to do the same with passwords. When I wipe out the profile the passwords are gone. Anyone know how I can correct this?

What I sync to profile server that gets it to work.

```
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.*"
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cookies.*" 
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Favicons.*"
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Login Data.*" 
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials" 
"C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft"
```

(note, in the roaming Microsoft I believe there were like 4 or 5 subfolders that were necessary but I just took the whole thing for simplicity since it was under 110 kb...

That works for the profile server...  and new vdi have the passwords, but I need to save to the users z drive in case I have to wipe out the users profile...

My specific problem is that I need to know where is exactly are the EDGE passwords are stored (locally) and any other pertinent files for those passwords, so I can export those file(s) to a different location. And then import those file(s) into a different computer when a user logs on. And I am aware that others have said login data in this location...
`C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default
But I have exported that whole folder before and the only thing that actually works is the bookmarks, so there is something else I am missing or the passwords are in a different location. I hope that is clear.

Comment: Can you open Edge?   Edge, Settings, Passwords, three dots ...   and Export Passwords.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: John, I would assume that I can do that, but I have not tried to do that as that is not relevant to what I need.

Comment: are you on a domain? Note that Edge likely uses the MS DPAPI to encrypt the credentials to the user account, and when the profile is wiped out, those keys are lost. Additionally those keys are based on the users password, so wiping out the profile and changing the password at the same time would make any backed up keys useless. see more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms995355(v=msdn.10)#introduction

Comment: It won't let me comment on my own question. I am on a domain. When we wipe a profile we don't reset a password. Is there any way to export those keys?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com//help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.